# Java - Diagnosing High CPU Usage

Tags: java, linux

After getting smacked around a little over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809257/java-100-cpu-usage) I went and grabbed the [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/) and got it nicely integrated with Eclipse. It's shown me some things about this application but now I'm running into limitations due to my simple lack of experience with Java.

The first chunk of code that's reporting high CPU usage (~49%) is the following. This reads strings over a sockets connction and hands them off. That all seems to work fine. **However, the call to `Runtime.freeMemory()` is reporting 41% CPU usage all by itself.** Why is that?

```
protected void PerformGarbageCollection()
{
    long oldMem = m_runtime.freeMemory();
    if (oldMem < 4000000)
    {
        m_runtime.gc();
        m_runtime.freeMemory();
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
    int loopCounter = 0;

    do
    {
        if (loopCounter++ > 10)
        {
            PerformGarbageCollection();
            loopCounter = 0;
        }

        try
        {
        //reading stuff...
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + " EXCEPTION in read loop: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

My first impression is that the second call to `Runtime.freeMemory()` is useless. After that, my impression is that this means of cleaning up after oneself is really crude. Is there some quirk of Java that I'm missing here, or is this just sloppy? **And, more importantly, what might be the 'right' way to do this?**

If I just disable that garbage collection, I wind up with `EventDispatchThread.run()` claiming 71% of the CPU. When I drill down to the first Java system call in the profiler, **I find `Window.setVisible()` using 7% of the CPU all by its lonesome.**

```
public final void CreateOTable(int x, int y, int xx, int yy, String suffix)
{
    JFrame oframe = new JFrame(OTable.title);
    OTable ot = new OTable(oframe);

    ot.setOpaque(true);
    ot.SetTScreen(m_TScreen);
    oframe.setContentPane(ot);
    oframe.setJMenuBar(new OTableMenu(ot));
    LoadOTable(ot, x, y, xx, yy, suffix);
    oframe.setSize(x, y);
    oframe.setLocation(xx, yy);
//==========================
    oframe.setVisible(true);  //This line
//==========================
    ScreenListener.otv.add(ot);
    oframe.addWindowListener(owner);
}
```

Again, I'm not sure what's going on here. Setting a UI element to visible should just be a once-and-done function call, right?

**Similarly, the below call to `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` is pulling 28% even after the dialog has been used to load the config file.**

```
String filename = config_file;
if (filename == "")
{
    filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter config file.");
    if (filename == null)
        filename = "";
}
```

What's really going on here? None of this seems like it should be devouring system resources, but my end users report sluggish GUI responses. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to call `Runtime.gc()` -- the JVM will run the GC automatically, whenever it needs to. As for profiling, profilers will sometimes give you false "hot spots" (see [this paper](http://www-plan.cs.colorado.edu/klipto/mytkowicz-pldi10.pdf)), so you may need some intuition about those false positives. You can also get the exact time that something takes by calling `System.nanoTime()` before and after the action, and subtracting the two to find out how many nanoseconds elapsed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll be doing some plain old log file debugging when I get back to the office Monday, and nanoseconds elapsed will be a handy metric.

Comment: That said, it makes sense that something like `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` will take a lot of your time. It doesn't return until the user find the config file they want, selects it, and then presses OK -- that's probably a _long_ time relative to a lot of other actions your program takes.

Comment: Yeah, but it's in that state of CPU consumption even after I've already used the dialog to load the file.